# Changing AD user password when "Password must change at next logon"is checked using ldap3

Tags: python-3.x, ldap, change-password, python-ldap, ldap3

I am working on an application which uses ldap3 to authenticate AD user and warn the users about their password expiry date. This works fine.

The issue happens when the user has checked "Password must change the password at next logon" and on binding results in failed bind with error code 773(ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE).

I want the user to use the old creds to bind and then call the `extend.microsoft.modify_password(user, "NewPassword")` method which is not possible since binding has failed..

The code is as below:

```
from ldap3 import  ALL, Connection, Server
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError, LDAPOperationResult

# Method to find the UAC values from the sum
def Calc(arr,sum):
    
# print(arr,sum)
    ds = sum
    res = []
    tt = arr
    donee  = True
    a = 0
    while donee:
        a = 0
        for i in tt:

            if i == ds:
                res.append(i)
                ds = 0
            if i > ds:
                break
            a+=1

        if ds == 0:
            donee  = False
            break

        tt = tt[0:a]
        #print(tt)
        ds = ds - tt[a-1]
        #print(ds)
        if ds < 0:
            break
        res.append(tt[a-1])
            
        #print(res)
    return res




uac_val = [1,2,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,2048,4096,8192,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,67108864]

# ldap server hostname and port
ldsp_server = f"ldaps://192.168.16.130"

# Root Dn
root_dn = "dc=DOMAIN,dc=com"

# AD user and password
ldap_user_name = 'user1'
ldap_password = 'OldPassword'

# User DN
user = f'cn={ldap_user_name},cn=Users,{root_dn}'

try:
    server = Server(ldsp_server, get_info=ALL,use_ssl=True)
    conn = Connection(server,
                user= user,
                password=ldap_password
                )
    
    if not conn.bind():
        print(conn.result)
        err   = str(conn.result).split("data")[1].split(',')[0].strip()

        if err == "773" :
            print(f"Password has expired for {ldap_user_name}")
            newpass = str(input("Please enter your new password: "))
            ii = conn.extend.microsoft.modify_password(user, newpass)
            print(ii)

            if ii:
                print("Password changed successfully!")
            else:
                print("Password change failed!")
        
        else:
            print("Binding failed due to:",conn.result)
        
        exit(0)

    else:
        print(f" Successful bind to ldap server ")

        print(f"Querying the user:DOMAIN/{ldap_user_name}")

        if conn.search(user,'(objectClass=user)',attributes= ['userAccountControl','pwdLastSet']):
            print(conn.entries[0])
            uacs  = str(conn.entries[0]).split('userAccountControl')[1].split(':')[1].strip()
            d = str(conn.entries[0]).split("pwdLastSet:")[1].split('.')[0].split('+')[0].strip()
            print("Last Password Changed Date:",d)
            #print("The Last Password Changed time is:",d)
            uac = int(uacs)
            print("UAC value is:",uac)
            ans = Calc(uac_val,uac)
            if ans.__contains__(65536):
                print("The user password never expires!!")
                


        else:
            print("Failed to get the user details")
            
        
        exit(0)


except (LDAPBindError) or (LDAPOperationResult)as E:
    print("Unsuccessfull binding with error:",conn.result)
    exit(0)
```

Is there an alternate approach for this or am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a few years since I did all this, but you should be able to modify the new password if you supply the old one. NB 'LDAP 3' is a protocol, and the only one you will find in the wild: not a product.

Comment: I have the code for more clarity. Can you confirm the approach is correct or it needs to change?